# Powershell script to install Python3, VS Code, and JupyterLab

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create a Powershell script I can use to quickly deploy a Python environment with Python3, VSCode, and Jupyter lab. This script should also check to see if the apps are already installed and if so continue without installing.

I have most of the script working, however, I'm struggling with one piece, which is getting Powershell to restart and continue running the script. I need to restart Powershell part way through the script so that Powershell will recognize that Python is installed and let me then install PIP to install JupyterLab.

So order of operation would be:

1. Check if Chocolatey is installed, if not, install.
2. Check if Python3 is installed, if not, install from Chocolatey.
3. Check if VSCode is installed, if not, install from Chocolatey.
4. Restart Powershell so it recognizes Python3 is installed (THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK)
5. Once Powershell restarts install PIP (doesn't come built in to chocolatey)
6. Check if JupyterLab is installed, if not, install.

Every part of my script is working except getting Powershell to restart to see Python is installed.

Any ideas?

Here is the script that I'm using:

```
# Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs

# Before running this script you may need to run the below command to allows scripts to be run.
# Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

# Check if Chocolatey is already installed
if (!(Get-Command choco -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Install Chocolatey package manager
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
}


# Check if Python 3 is already installed
if (!(Get-Command python -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Install Python 3 for all users
    choco install -y python3 --installargs 'ADD_EXPLORER_CONTEXT_MENU_OPENPYTHON=1'
}


# Check if Visual Studio Code is already installed
if (!(Get-Command code -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Install Visual Studio Code for all users
    choco install -y vscode --installargs '--add-to-path=false --install-extension ms-vscode.python'
}


# Restart PowerShell so it recognizes Python
function Restart-PowerShell
{
    if((Get-PSHostProcessInfo).ProcessName.Contains('powershell_ise'))
    {
        Start-Process 'powershell_ise.exe'
    } else {
        Start-Process 'powershell.exe'
    }
    exit
}

# Install pip that doesn't come default in chocolatey
    choco install pip -y --installargs 'ADD_CMD_TO_PATH=System'


# Check if JupyterLab is already installed
if (!(Get-Command jupyter-lab -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Install JupyterLab
    pip install jupyterlab
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Install process complete - Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: I believe you would only need to reload the path environment variables into your session. Worth a shot.

Comment: How do I do that within the powershell script?

Comment: after your installs, run: `$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User") `.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, Actually that did work. I had an error when I copied and pasted.

Comment: aww man, welp, was worth a shot.